# Need to change websocket baseURL in stubby4j from ws://0.0.0.0:<port>/ws/ to ws://0.0.0.0:<port>/ how to change

Tags: stubby4j

Need to change websocket baseURL in stubby4j from ws://0.0.0.0:/ws/ to ws://0.0.0.0:/  how to change

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the WS URL prefix is not configurable. In other words, it will run on /ws/ only